# Sort command on more than one field

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sort

I have a file with contents

```
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.56
192.168.1.43
10.1.1.23
```

When I gave

```
$ sort -h -t. -k3,4 sort_test.txt 
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.23
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.43
192.168.1.56
```

Couldn't understand why 10.1.1.23 comes before 10.1.1.3. I thought, since two fields are used for comparison, second field is used when there is a tie and it should work as normal sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sorts `.23` after `.3`:

```
$ sort -h -t. -k3,3 -k4,4 sort_test.txt 
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
10.1.1.23
192.168.1.43
192.168.1.56
```

Comment: Why ? Though I have given -h option

Comment: When sorting over a range `-k3,4`, the option `-h` only applies to the first field.  The remainder of the range is sorted alphabetically.  When specifying `-k3,3 -k4,4`, the `-h` option applies to the first field in each range.  (And, yes, this is bizarre counter-intuitive behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

In the case is better use `-n` instead `-h` option.
But the main thing is possible expansion of `.` For my opinion some versions of `sort` operate -t arguments as *regexp*, so to be sure I'd offer to escape `.`

```
sort -nt\. -k3,4 sort_test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**An understanding of why sort is behaving "weird"**

since you are sorting from key 3 to key 4 sort will ignore all other fields

```
 sort -h -t. -k3,4 sort_test.txt
```

will result in

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.23
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.43
192.168.1.56
```

extracting keys 3 and 4 from your results will explain why sort places `192.168.1.3` above `10.1.1.3`

```
1.1
1.2
1.2------>192.168.1.2
1.23------> 10.1.1.23
1.3------>10.1.1.3
1.3
1.4
1.43
1.56
```

Hence, we see the reason why sort behaving the way it should...sorting from keys 1 to 4 will therefore get you the correct result.

```
sort -h -t. -k1,4 sort_test.txt
```

Comment: My problem is about why `10.1.1.23` above `10.1.1.3`

Comment: @user3539, and Xorg: -h is a numeric compare --  you are in fact comparing the number 1.23 with the number 1.3; with -V you will obtain what you expect (see my solution)

Comment: @JJoao..no need to argue...refer to sort man pages or this link:http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usort.htm

Answer (score 0):

`-n` and `-h` activate numeric comparisons; in this situation when we say "`k3,4`", `k3` will get a float point number (k3=1.23 < 1.3) and k4="".

With "`-V`" the behavior is better: version numbers 1.2 < 1.3 < 1.23.

```
sort  -t. -k3,4V
```

applied to

```
192.168.10.3
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.56
192.168.1.43
10.1.1.23
192.168.9.3
```

returns

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.3
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
10.1.1.23
192.168.1.43
192.168.1.56
192.168.9.3
192.168.10.3
```

The same result will be obtain with:

```
sort -t. -k3V
sort -V -t. -k3
```